# Cell.getNumericCellValue returns null value when reading Excel file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

Following is the code to print the sum of the cells in the same row in a loop. When I run, the first loop works fine and I get the value of the sum but during the second loop, it throws the null pointer exception at line `double z= cell.getNumericCellValue();` after printing the value of `z`.

```
try{
      FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/m.y/My Documents/test.xls");

      HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
      HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 //   HSSFCell cell = null;
      Row r = sheet.getRow(0);
      Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
      Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
      double summ=1.0;

        for(int i =1 ; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){

            for(int j=1; j<r.getLastCellNum();j++)
            {          
                cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j); 
              //  if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType())
             //   {  
                  double z= cell.getNumericCellValue(); 
                   System.out.println(z);                  
                   summ=summ+z;  

             //    }                                     
            }  
             System.out.println(summ);
             Cell mycell1=r.createCell(3);
                   mycell1.setCellValue(summ); 
                   summ=0.0;        
                 }    

    file.close();    
    FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/m.y/My Documents/test.xls");
    workbook.write(outFile);
    outFile.close();   


}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
```

Note: The excel file can be like:

```
Name  sub1   Sub2
m      2      3
n      5      6
j      4      9
```

Comment: Can you post the output of your program, and add a comment to the line that throws the error?

Comment: The cell may be null,you should check it cell==null.

Comment: First it prints the content of the cell i.e z (For example for above excel, 2.0 3.0) and then sum 5.0, after that second loop, it prints the cells (5.0 6.0) but no sum and throws
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at reading.Reading.main(Reading.java:88)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try{
        FileInputStream file = null;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/m.y/My Documents/test.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            double summ = 1.0;
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int i = 0;
                double z = 0.0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        z = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    }
                    System.out.println(z);
                    summ = summ + z;
                    i++;
                    //    }                                     
                }
                System.out.println(summ);
                Cell mycell1 = r.createCell(3);
                mycell1.setCellValue(summ);
                summ = 0.0;
            }
            file.close();
            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/m.y/My Documents/test.xls");
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have certain string cells before numeric data, with iterator, I get this exception, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell

Comment: manage i variable accordingly whatever cell you have before that and whatever value you want to capture as numeric

Comment: It gives the null pointer exception in this line only, z = cell.getNumericCellValue();